# make admin.css in my child theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, admin-css

i want hide elements of admin with css file "my-admin.css"
I put css file "my-admin.css" at the root of my child theme wordpress
and use this code in functions.php

but does not work?

there may be an error?

thank you ! :

```
<?php
/*
activation theme
*/
function wpm_enqueue_styles(){
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpm_enqueue_styles' );

/*
admin stylesheet
*/
function wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-admin-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-admin.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to wpse! First make sure that the file was loaded, check your devtools under network tab, select css and refresh page, if you see your file and it have status 200 it means its loaded and the problem is probably css targets or css s[pecificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_template_directory_uri()` function gets the URL to the *parent* theme. The equivalent function for child themes is `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

However these days the proper function to use to get the URL for a file in a child theme is [`get_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/):

```
function wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-admin-css', get_theme_file_uri( 'my-admin.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp245372_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
```